# Using AJAX to call product tabs of a simple product

Tags: magento-1.7, configurable-product, ajax

When I select an option of a configurable product I want to load that specific Part Number's product tabs. I assume AJAX would be the easiest way to do this but I am unfamiliar with using  AJAX. If anyone can point me in the right direction or has a different suggestion on how to accomplish this it will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Starting out with AJAX in Magento might be a big leap. I'd like to suggest first starting out with familiarizing yourself with AJAX first.
Some basic tutorials

- [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp)
- [AJAX & jQuery by IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-jquery-ajax/)
- [AJAX with prototype (the lib used by Magento)](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/prototype/prototype_ajax_tutorial.htm)

When you have a good basic understanding of how AJAX works checkout [subeshpokhrel's ajaxify](https://github.com/subeshpokhrel/ajaxify) extension to get you started on the basics of AJAX in Magento. That should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Awesome appreciate the response. I looked around the w3 schools tutorials but i will check out the rest of these.

Answer (score 0):

So after looking around and playing with some code I found what I wanted to do. So i wanted to load product tabs of single products on my product page and figured i would need some type of AJAX, Prototype, or jQuery solution. I experimented with AJAX.Updater [Ajax.Updater API](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/ajax/Ajax/Updater/) and it didn't seem to do what I wanted. Also from my understanding I would have to have a custom module in place to execute this the way I wanted. In the end I used jQuery.on() [jQuery.on() API](http://api.jquery.com/on/) mixed with some prototype calls and jQuery calls to select the elements I needed to load and where to put them.

Comment: yea, if you're going to modify how the core works, it's suggested to extend the portion of the core you're going to work with. It's also best practice to create a custom module in the app/code/local code pool to do this. Or if you were just going to extend a core module with a custom block, you'd also create a copy of the core module's folder structure ( /etc, /controllers/, /Block, /Model ) but only what you need for your custom functionality.

Also, be cautious when you're mixing your JavaScript. If you can accomplish your goal in one library, that's better, or some portions in plain JS.